# Prevent multiple loading of Google maps on a single element

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am binding a hidden DIV element with Google maps, when the DIV element is being shown. The user can show and hide the DIV multiple times. I want Google Maps to be loaded and bound to the element only once, and not everytime the DIV is (hidden and) shown. Is there any API method from Google Maps which will check if the element is already bound to a Google Map object?

Comment: Where and when are you lonking google maps to div? If you are doing it on page load you should get what you want.

Comment: I am loading the map to div when showing the hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

```
map.getDiv()
```

gives you the current div the map is bound to.
Hope this is helpful. You can easily implement the functionality.

Initialize the Map once. Then just hide and show the div as per requirement.
Just make sure to Initialize the Map when the Div is visible or else you will run into problems of improper map rendering. (at least this happens if you have bootstrap).